# Create a Cucumber feature in Gherkin with an empty List argument

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I'm using Cucumber in Java, and have written a scenario that takes a `List` as an argument, i.e.

```
And the following ids are within the range: 1, 2
```

This works successfully with the method definition:

```
@Given("^the following ids are within the range: (.*)$")
public void ids_are_within_range(List<String> idsWithinRange) {
    this.idsWithinRange = idsWithinRange
}
```

However I have a problem if I try to pass no IDs into the list:

```
And the following ids are within the range:
```

The test simply doesn't execute and tells me I need to implement the relevant test methods. It thinks that the line ending in a list is actually a different method that doesn't take any arguments:

```
Wrong test finished. Last started: [] stopped: Scenario: Search for manifests, none of which are within a date range in the data platform; class org.junit.runner.Description
Test '.Feature: Restful CRUD service for manifest searches.Scenario: Search for manifests, none of which are within a date range in the data platform' ignored
...
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
...
@Given("^and the following ids are within the range:$")
```

How do I get an empty `List` to be passed into my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a **workaround** (not an elegant solution), you could set your step definition as follows:

```
And the following ids are within the range: ,
```

You'll receive an initialized empty `ArrayList` in your method.
Hope it helps. Anyway, I'll be waiting for other answers, maybe someone can give a better solution.

Comment: I like that - I don't think it's too ugly because the comma makes it clear it's a list as opposed to actually nothing. And it works. Thanks!

Comment: This workaround (and the question itself) seems to me, to beg for a re-think of the scenarios. If you have a scenario in which some id values are supplied, and a scenario in which no id values are supplied, then this ought to be two scenarios, with this one having a "given no id values are supplied", or some such phrasing.